# Pegar dados retornados via json com PHP

Tags: php, json

Galera, já tentei de todas as formas capturar com php os dados da URL: https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/time/slug/artilheiroCoral/1
Mas não consigo, tentei por cUrl, tentei salvar a página retornada, enfim, tudo que tentei foi sem sucesso! Sempre retorna false...

```
$url = "https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/time/slug/artilheiroCoral/1";

$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);

$result = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);


var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Já que tentou de várias maneiras acho que seria interessante incluir quais foram suas tentativas, afinal é impossível saber o que você já tentou.

Answer (score 1):

Para transformar direto em Array pode fazer assim :

```
   <?php 
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}

$json = get_web_page('https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/time/slug/artilheiroCoral/1');
var_dump($json);
```

Comment: Na verdade não consigo nem recuperar os dados..

Comment: Qual erro aparece ?

Comment: o retorno do vardump é false

Comment: Ajustei e testei funcionando :)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: Dá um up na resposta para rankear ela.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar um User-Agent, para que o CURL torne-se mais próximo de um navegador comum, [veja uma lista de UA aqui](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

---

Para definir um User-Agent existem duas maneira, *escolha uma delas*:

**Acrescentando `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` (`-A`):**

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36');
```

---

**Via cabeçalho (usando `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`):**

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
  'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
]);
```

---

Em qualquer uma das situações irá enviar o cabeçalho de `User-Agent`, que deve ser suficiente para se conectar, *se não adicione também o `Referer`, por exemplo*.

*<sub><sub>Estou ignorando completamente aspectos de segurança relacionados ao código original</sub></sub>.*